# accessing class field in c++

Tags: c++, class, this, field

I can't have an access to the class'es field in the following C++ code:

```
class Human
{
     string address;
 public:
     void setAddress( string address )
     {
         this.address = address;
     }
};
```

This code will result into an error "error C2228: left of '.address' must have class/struct/union". What's the correct way of doing it?

Comment: Unlike JavaScript you don't need to use "this". Here it would be usual to give the function parameter a different name to avoid ambiguity.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`this` is a pointer to your current instance, so you should use `->` instead of a dot.

Answer (score 2):

```
  class Human
{
     string m_address;
 public:
     void setAddress( string address )
     {
         m_address = address;
     }
};
```

Unlike JavaScript you don't need to use "this". Here it would be usual to give the function parameter a different name to avoid ambiguity